# Intellij instead of Blackberry JDE

Tags: blackberry, intellij-idea, blackberry-jde

I'm trying to develop a few apps for blackberry and the [IDE they have](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/downloads/jde.jsp) I'm really not interested in that.  I used to use eclipse but after I used IntelliJ IDEA I really don't want to downgrade just for a BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse.

Does anyone know how I can successfully develop in IntelliJ w/o debugging issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely [build BlackBerry apps with IntelliJ](http://javaandjava.blogspot.com/2010/05/ant-script-for-blackberry-development.html) after some configuration, but for debugging I think you'll still need to use the standalone JDE or the Eclipse plugin.

Comment: It seems they at figured out the [debugging the test](http://javaandjava.blogspot.com/2010/05/debugging-tests-for-blackberry.html) as well